# Can i use this statement

Tags: php

i this a valid command

```
$fp = fopen($hyphen + ".html","w");
```

I have declared $hyphen already.But it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Just as a sidenote, so no insult intended, but `It doesn't seem to be working` is no problem/error description.

Comment: Saying 'thank you' to the people who stopped doing what they were doing so they could help you would be polite as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string concatenation in php works by using `.` (instead of `+` like other languages use (java, javascript, c++ ...)), so you have to change your script to this:

```
$fp = fopen($hyphen . ".html","w");
                // ^^^ this has to be a dot, not a plus
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope. Join the two parts of the filename using a dot instead of a plus sign, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error. Try:

```
$fp = fopen($hyphen . ".html","w");
```